# Get current bitrate on hls playback in Android or Ios browsers

Tags: javascript, android, html, http-live-streaming, bitrate

Using the html video tag to play HLS streams, How may I check to see what is the current playing bitrate?
If possible without using any 3rd party video playback library

Comment: Did you find a solution ?